# primeng picklist buttons width shrink

Tags: css, angular, primeng

[image]I am using primeng picklist. I found that when the options length in the target or source control are bigger then the picklist control buttons in the middle gets smaller. My picklist code follows

```
<p-pickList [source]="availableFormula" [target]="selectedFormula" sourceHeader="Available Formula"
      targetHeader="Selected Formula" [responsive]="true" filterBy="Name" dragdrop="true" dragdropScope="cars"
      sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by Formula" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by Formula" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}"
      [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" showSourceControls="false" [showTargetControls]="false" (onSourceSelect)="formulaSelectEvent($event)"
      (onTargetSelect)="formulaSelectEvent($event)">
      <ng-template let-availableFormula pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
          <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{availableFormula.Name}}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-pickList>
```

[image]

I tried the following in CSS override to make it not shrink but nothing worked.

```
 .ui-picklist-buttons{
width: 100% !important;
```

}

Comment: How can we help you if you do not replicate the problem ? Please share the minimum required code that replicates your specific problem.

Comment: What code is required ?

Comment: how can we help with image and small piece of css that you asked

Comment: i added my picklist code

Comment: Does the css style rule get applied on the element ? Do you see it when you inspect that element ? ( event if it's crossed out )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the width of the buttons.

The problem is that the `picklist-buttons` and `picklist-listwrapper` are declared as `table-cell` and `td's` increase their width depending on content. ( Unlike a block elements )

If you just want to have fixed column widths use `table-layout: fixed`  on the `ui-picklist`. If the problem is that one list has a very long word inside it, use `word-break: break-word` on the `picklist-listwrapper` or on the `ui-picklist-item`

See example below

```css
.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  width: 20%;
  background: blue;
}
.list {
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
}

.not-fixed .list {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!–– with table-layout: fixed  but no break-word -->
<table class="fixed">
  <tr>
    <td class="list">40percent</td>
    <td class="buttons">button</td>
    <td class="list">veryveryveasasasarylongtextthatdoesntfitin40percent</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!–– with break-word -->
<table class="not-fixed">
  <tr>
    <td class="list">40percent</td>
    <td class="buttons">button</td>
    <td class="list">veryveryveasasasarylongtextthatdoesntfitin40percent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried something like this on my css override .ui-picklist-listwrapper{
 word-wrap: break-word !important;
  }     It didnt work

Comment: @SGN can you show me a full image ( if you cannot replicate the code here ) ?

Comment: I added the picture.

Comment: @SGN try `ui-picklist-item { word-break: break-all;}` . word-break not word-wrap

Comment: it works now.I dont think the question needs a downvote

Comment: If it works, please rate my answer and accept it. I removed the downvote. It had a downvote because you need to replicate your specific problem with code ( that actually runs and replicates the problem ). Not with images.